# blender script: how to write to text object

Tags: python, blender

I use blender 2.6 and add a text object with

```
bpy.ops.object.text_add(location=(x,y,z))
```

and just want to set the text and cannot figure that out. I found in the python console that I can

```
bpy.data.texts['Text.001'].write("my text")
```

but (also generally) am confused how to reference the last created object to perform something on it. In tutorials there is the `primitive_MESHTYPE_add` shortcuts which return not the object created. Can you tell me how to do `Text.new()`?

Comment: guess i am fine with
```
   bpy.ops.object.text_add(enter_editmode=True,
        location = (x,y,z))
    bpy.ops.font.delete()
    bpy.ops.font.text_insert(text="mytext")
```

Answer (score 15):

```
bpy.ops.object.text_add()
ob=bpy.context.object
ob.data.body = "my text"
```

Comment: I'd use ```ob = bpy.data.objects['Text']``` just to make sure you're selecting the Text object and not any other. Another important thing to mention, is that by this method, you can edit any other property of the text (like, font, size, bold/italic, etc) by assigning ```ob.data.PROP_NAME``` - a reference to all properties can be found at: https://docs.blender.org/api/2.79/bpy.types.TextCurve.html. Also, this should be done in Object Mode.

Answer (score 10):

If you plan on creating a lot of text objects I would recommend using low level code instead of bpy.ops in order to increase the speed of code execution:

```
import bpy

myFontCurve = bpy.data.curves.new(type="FONT",name="myFontCurve")
myFontOb = bpy.data.objects.new("myFontOb",myFontCurve)
myFontOb.data.body = "my text"
bpy.context.scene.objects.link(myFontOb)
bpy.context.scene.update()
```

Comment: Update for Blender 2.8+ :

```bpy.context.collection.objects.link(myFontOb)```

Comment: But what if you have some extra logic and want to convert to mesh with some modifiers? Like this?
```
 "txt = bpy.ops.object.text_add(enter_editmode=False, align='WORLD', location=(0, 0, 0), scale=(2, 2, 2))",        
    "bpy.context.scene.objects.get(txt)",
    "txt.data.body      = 'Number 5'",   
    "bpy.ops.font.open(filepath='C:\\WINDOWS\\Fonts\\Poppins-Bold.otf')",    
    "bpy.ops.object.modifier_add(type='SOLIDIFY')",
    "bpy.context.object.modifiers['Solidify'].thickness = 0.5",
    "bpy.ops.object.modifier_add(type='REMESH')",
```